# Do not select row if column is not distinct

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table phone_numbers
have sample data:

```
phone_number, id  
09123456789, 1234  
09876543210, 1234  
09012463579, 5678
```

I want the output as:

```
phone_number, id  
09012463579, 5678
```

Is there a way I can use `having count()` function after a `where` clause?
`select distinct` not working also

Comment: please read the last comment on my answer. It is regarding your codes' readability and performance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe this is the simplest correct solution:

```
  SELECT MAX (phone_number) as phone_number, id
    FROM phone_numbers
GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT (*) = 1
```

With test data:

```
WITH phone_numbers AS
(
SELECT '09123456789' AS phone_number , 1234 AS ID FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '09876543210' AS phone_number , 1234 AS ID FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '09012463579' AS phone_number , 5678 AS ID FROM dual
)
  SELECT MAX (phone_number) as phone_number, id
    FROM phone_numbers
GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT (*) = 1

phone_number |  id   | 
----------------------
09012463579  |  5678 |
```

I hope I helped!

Comment: the user is not asking for max (phone number

Comment: @nikhilsugandh technically, he is neither getting it. writing `min (phone_number)` would do the same. thank you for downvote though, without looking at the code and/or understanding it.

Comment: the user is asking for phone number as "Do not select row if column is not distinct
"   describes as select row when column is distinct

Comment: @nikhilsugandh I wrote a comment to your answer to help you understand your error. Your code gives the wrong result.

Comment: check Zaynul Abadin Tuhi's code down below thats is logical to understand i meant

Comment: @nikhilsugandh although Zaynuls' answer is more obvious, it is also accessing the same table twice. That can become a problem in future, especially as we see that there can be more than one row per user ID in OP's table. I find it logical to write code as good performance-wise as I can and to avoid redundant and potentially problematic piece of coding. (I had no desire to continue this discussion and thus compare my code with someone else's in this manner, but OP seems to have read what you have been saying)

Comment: great neither do i

Comment: hi all, thanks for all the help. what worked best for me was the 
  
"with phone_numbers as" from Goran, and then the conditional script provided by Zaynul. thanks all! - andrea

Comment: @gravestones does my answer helps to you?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need conditional `count`

```
select * from phone_numbers 
where id in (
    select id from
    phone_numbers
    group by id
    having count(*)=1
              )
```

or use exist

```
select * from phone_numbers t1
  where exists ( select 1 from phone_numbers t2
                  where t1.id=t2.id
                  group by t2.id
                  having count(*)=1
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select f.phone_number
          ,f.id
    from ( select t.phone_number
                 ,t.id
                 ,count(*) over( partition by t.id ) as dpl
           from table t ) f
    where f.dpl = 1
```

Comment: table t  = your table